# Android: When asked to drawARGB, it shows for a split second only

Tags: android, canvas, draw

when i try to change the screen color from black, i use the command drawARGB once, and i intend it to stay that color i asked, and other drawings will occur on top of it, but it only shows once, for a split second, and turns black again...

here is the code, if u wonder it all works fine, other than the drawARGB...

this is part of a live wallpaper.

```
public void drawFrame() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       c = null;
       try {
           c = holder.lockCanvas();
           if (c != null) {
               // draw something
            height = c.getHeight();
            width = c.getWidth();
            drawScreenColor();
            frame++;
           }
       } finally {
           if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
       }
         mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawStrip);
            if (clearToRun) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawStrip, 1000 / 60);
            }
    }

    void drawScreenColor() {

        if (isFirstFrame) {
            c.drawARGB(255,255,0,0);
            isFirstFrame = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to your "first frame" code.

```
if (isFirstFrame) {
    c.drawARGB(255,255,0,0);
    isFirstFrame = false;
}
```

So, this will execute once, set `isFirstFrame` to false, and never execute again. The way a `Canvas` works is that all elements must be redrawn every frame (elements from the previous frame do not stick around). So, remove the `isFirstFrame` check, and make this the first call in your `drawFrame` method; everything following it will be drawn on top.

Comment: I know that, but u don't understand, i want it to be drawn once, why than, when i draw random bitmaps or lines (drawLine), every frame that is everytime it calls, and in random positions, they do stay on the canvas, unless drawn on them?

Comment: You'd have to show that part of the code. There's no reason they'd stick around, unless you didn't call `invalidate()`.

Comment: my other part is just another function that just has drawLine(x,y,endx,endy,paint) (the x and y are changing every time), that's all... and it does stick to the canvas...this is a service (live wallpaper) after all, i am not sure if i can call invalidate.

Comment: Thing is, the `Canvas` should be cleared on the beginning of every frame. (Even in wallpapers; you can see that demoed [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html), where he redraws every circle every frame.) The idea is that all the items you want on the `Canvas` would be redrawn each frame.

Comment: but it's a bit stupid, for instance what if i have a large back ground image right? that stays the same with out change the entire life cycle, and i only add small bitmap sprites around it, that only they need to be updated, it would just take a bunch of memory only to draw that background image every time... is there a smart way to do that?

Comment: Well let's see... the internet is actually providing mixed solutions. Most say to retain the bitmap and redraw it (in the event that it's a background), but some posts say that [things drawn should be automatically retained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110913/setting-background-bitmap-in-live-wallpaper).